# Disable Hot Corners in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, charms-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to disable “top left click switches to metro app” behaviour in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/485521/is-there-a-way-to-disable-top-left-click-switches-to-metro-app-behaviour-in-wi)

Whenever I move my mouse cursor to the top-left/bottom-right/top-right corners, the charms bar and the small start screen preview popup. This is very annoying since I don't use the new Metro/Modern/Microsoft-style UI.

Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/485526/127618 and http://superuser.com/a/460913/127618